# Узнать чем зашифрован текст (Имеется хеш)

Tags: php, flash, шифрование, криптография, md5

Ребят, нужна помощь...
Закодирован айпишник, т.е. "178.172.186.213" (Без кавычек)
Нужно узнать каким алгоритмом, и есть его хеш, т.е. уже зашифрованный. Вот он:
"211f992e9c89202eb4881abb19581e0c" (Также без кавычек). Ещё - он скорее закодирован в РНР, или Flash'ем.
Помогите, возможно даже за деньги...

Немного от себя о своей задаче, может поможет... Мне нужно выявить прямую ссылку на mp4 файл с видео, файл отображается на сайте через Uppod Flash Player, путь до файла имеет такой вид:

> http://s1.kinostok.tv:81/flv/**211f992e9c89202eb4881abb19581e0c**/16347.mp4

где на месте жирного текста зашифрованный IP адресс. Если по этой ссылке пройти с другого IP то ссылка на видео будет другой, и вам, вместо того чтобы дать скачать файл выдаст "upsВАШIP". Вот, вроде бы всё.

Comment: А вы уверены, что в этом участвует только IP? Вполне возможно, что он просто отображается на странице ошибки, а адрес формируется, исходя из каких-то других соображений.

Comment: Уверен, вот только не уверен что он изначально не преобразован както.

Comment: Скорее всего была какая-то соль перед md5, поэтому маловероятно ответить на твой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов алгоритма формирования этой строки очень много (можно даже сказать - бесконечно много). Если повезет, то можно конечно и угадать, но шансов практически нет.

Как правило есть некая база, в которой хранятся вот такие идентификаторы и параметры клиента (IP, идентификатор браузера и любые другие параметры о которых побеспокоится разработчик). Идентификатор может формироваться **любым** способом.
Вот навскидку что там может быть:

1. Случайная строка в base16;
2. Любой хеш-алгоритм, на входе которого могут быть:

   - IP-адрес
   - Любые другие параметры соединения
   - Соль
   - Опять таки любая случайная строка
3. Комбинация вариантов пунктов 1 и 2. То есть могут быть вызваны несколько хеш алгоритмов последовательно с разными параметрами на входе

В общем если сразу не получилось - оставьте эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на MD5. 32-символа в шестнадцатеричном представлении. Но шифровался не напрямую. Скорее всего был предварительно преобразован. Прямой `MD5('178.172.186.213')` дает `6152a7b1941a7e8e06366100b95015e1`. В чем кодировалось PHP или Flash сказать невозможно, один и тот-же алгоритм везде возвращает одинаковый результат.

Comment: Да, похож, но пробовал и двумя мд5 и тремя - не то. Но формат однозачно похож, ещё бы узнать как его изменили то...

Comment: Только перебором и угадайкой. Варианты: вместо точек что-то другое, IP преобразовать в число, перевернуть символы и т.д. И все это умножить на возможность многократного MD5.

Comment: Да попробуй еще связки с именем пользователя, с id и т. д. И как вариант сервисы  типа http://hashcrack.in

Comment: А ещё можно маленькую деталь? Почему :
$p = "178.172.186.213";
echo md5($p);
Отличается от
$p = '178.172.186.213';
echo md5($p);

От кавычек зависит криптование?

Comment: Посмотри внимательно. Вероятно что-то упущено.

У меня:

    $p = '178.172.186.213'; echo md5($p) . '<br />';
    $p = "178.172.186.213"; echo md5($p) . '<br />';

Возвращает:

    6152a7b1941a7e8e06366100b95015e1
    6152a7b1941a7e8e06366100b95015e1

Comment: Имхо бесполезное занятие, если только не надеяться, что админы - идиоты. Я бы шифровал, например, так:

    $str = md5(md5($ip).$useragent.'xj349dsa');

А то еще и session_id() добавить можно.

Comment: солидарен с @Sh4dow, вопрос из разряда "угадай мелодию" или "поле-чудес"...

Сектор Шанс на барабане ^.^

Answer (score 0):

В инете есть сервисы для определения, какая хэш-функция используется. Сам пользовался ими, вот на тостере есть [тема](https://toster.ru/q/19817), в которой приведены 2 из них:

- http://regenboog.yellosoft.us
- http://www.onlinehashcrack.com/

А так их дофига, наверно, надо искать по сочетанию 'hash crack'.